# Webstorm says Promise is an unresolved type

Tags: webstorm, jestjs

Using WebStorm 10.0

I am currently learning Node Js  and installing all of the component it need to work .
So i chose to used Jest to test my work, i already installed Jest to my frameworks and languages inside the WebStorm but its keeps showing **Promise** as **unresolved type** how do i fix it in WebStorm?

[image: unresolved type]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Promise type is not a part of Jest module; please try enabling '`ECMAScript 6`' library for your project in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`. If it's not available in your version (it is there since WebStorm 11), try downloading typescript stubs for '`promise`' library (promise.d.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Also, check your tsconfig.json. Either add `es6` or `es2015.promise` to your `tsconfig.lib[]`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the vanilla Javascript Promise and also got an `unresolved type` error message in phpStorm.

I fixed it by downloading this file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/master/src/lib/es2015.promise.d.ts

And imported it into phpStorm like this:

Go to `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`. Then click on `Add` type in a name, choose Global (if you like), click on the `+` symbol and choose `Add file`. Select `es2015.promise.d.ts` from your drive and click `OK` two times.

The underline disappears and I got intellisense now!